# Google drive File Downloads

Tags: files, downloads, drive, google

After Downloading a file, it automatically gets converted to html format and on accessing it I can see Google sign in page only

Comment: You should tell us which steps you take to download that file.

Comment: Sounds like you're downloading the file without converting it. If it's an office document, try "File" > "Download as".

Comment: `Ctrl`+`S` is not meant to be used in the web browser.

Comment: Unless they want to save the page on which they are or some sort of contents... @tatsu.

Comment: this user obviously would prefer we adapt our language to his/her non-tech tongue and prefereably eliminate excess information. I evaluate the level of each user. if this user is erroneously using `Ctrl`+`S` in google drive  do you think they'll **ever** have a use for this keybind in the browser for the next five years to come? baby steps. he/she won't be saving content from webpages intentionally for a while to come.